# Object changed handle with custom Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have defined a custom Serializer

```
class CustomSerializer
  def self.dump(obj)
    obj.to_h
  end

  def self.load(obj)
    CustomClass.new(obj)
  end
end
```

and used in a active record model

```
class Klass < ActiveRecord::Base
   serialize :my_column, CustomSerializer
end
```

Now when use an object of Klass `k = Klass.first` I always see `k.changed? = true`

I understand this is because of the class reference introduced by serializer I have defined

```
k.my_column_was # #<CustomClass:0x00007fd9063d6288>
k.my_column # #<CustomClass:0x00007fd9080d9088>
```

How can I fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails 5 [Attributes API](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html) will allow you to manipulate how [dirty tracking](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Type/Value.html) is handled.

This is the recommended method for domain specific serialization.

> For more complex cases, such as conversion to or from your application domain objects, consider using the ActiveRecord::Attributes API.

For rails < 5 unfortunately the documents state:

> A notable side effect of serialized attributes is that the model will be updated on every save, even if it is not dirty.

Which is what you have stumbled across

Comment: How can I manipulate in rails 5? I want to keep `k.my_column # #<CustomClass:0x00007fd9063d6288>`

Comment: @ayushlodhi to help with implementation I would need to know what `my_column` is natively so that we can implement an appropriate type casting scheme. If you would like to look into this yourself just google rails attributes api (lots of documentation and articles). For example here is how JSON type is implemented https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/type/json.rb

Comment: I got it now. Thanks a ton :)